# Central Shared folder for all users of my app

Tags: file, ftp, zip, dropbox, sharing

I have an app which access an app folder on a per user basis.

I also want to be able to have a specific folder within my dropbox - which ALL users of my application can access the files within - kinda like a shared folder between every user on the app.

Is this possible - and how do you do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is simply an unsupported feature for dropbox - and will most likely be using amazon cloud instead.